# Editable / patchable resources within dylib?

Tags: macos, dylib, mach-o

Is there any way to embed resources (e.g. strings / images) within a Mach-O dylib such that they are editable post-build? Similar to resources in PE files.

I know I should be using Bundles instead, but humour me ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I embed data into a Mac OS X mach-o binary file's TEXT Section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604673/how-do-i-embed-data-into-a-mac-os-x-mach-o-binary-files-text-section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `-sectcreate` linker flag to embed some data into a binary. See this [Embedding Data](https://web.archive.org/web/20111016063642/http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/10/07/embedding-data/) blog post for a complete explanation of the procedure.

Comment: Link is dead, which is why just adding links instead of responses is discouraged here.

Comment: Link is back thanks to the Internet Archive.